# I am stumped by this question on individual probability

Tags: probability, self-study

It says:
Based on 2000 census data, the median annual household income was $39,000.

Show work by writing out the individual probability formulas for P(X = x) and letting C(n,x) = "n choose x"

And the question:
Among five randomly selected U.S. households, find the probability that four or more have
incomes exceeding $39,000 per year

Answer (score 2):

The definition of median means $P(X \geq m) = P(X \leq m) = 0.5$

Hence the probability a random chosen individual is above or below the median is $\frac{1}{2}$.

The number of ways $4$ or more households can be above median income is $5 \choose 4 $$= 5$ plus $5 \choose 5$$ = 1$.  Each of those outcomes has probability $(\frac{1}{2})^5$ as each house as equal probability of being above or below the median.

Hence the probability is

$$P = (\frac{1}{2})^5 \times 6 = \frac{6}{2^5}$$

Alternatively you can recognise this as a Binomial(5,0.5) distribution and work it out that way.

Comment: Please consult our wiki for [tag:self-study] questions.